# In which field $K$, elliptic curve is connected?

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

In which field $K$, elliptic curve is connected?

If $K$＝$\Bbb C $, elliptic curve over $\Bbb C $ is just homeo to torus, so connected.
But in other field? If $K$＝$\Bbb R $, $y^2＝x^3-x$ seems disconnected(I don't have confident because point at infinity may connect disconnected pieces).
What about other fields?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ does not have a point at infinity.  Perhaps you are thinking of one-dimensional real projective space (which might be a well-behaved space for studying algebraic varieties).

Comment: In which topology?

Comment: I mean  with respect to Zariski topology ( the field is arbitrary field, so we have no choice but to Zariski topology, I think).

Comment: the curve $y^2=x^3-x$ over $\mathbb{R}$(or any non-algebraically closed field) has many more points than the drawing suggest because Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is not true over $\mathbb{R}$ and hence there are many maximal ideals that are not represented by a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, of course, if you work over $\mathbb{R}$(or any local field) you can put a topology on $\mathbb{R}$  points of your curve(which are different from Spec or even maxspec) and there is no reason for this to be connected.

Comment: I think it is important to understand the difference between $k$-points of a variety and topological points of a variety which is defined over $k$.